# Primefaces file upload changes browser tab title to file name

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

If I upload a file with primefaces dialog the browser tab title is changed form the application name to the file name after the upload. This occurs with Firefox (41.0.2) and Chrome (46.0.2490.80). With Internet Explorer it does not occur. I am using Mojarra 2.2.12 and Primefaces 5.3. How can I suppress this?

```
<p:fileUpload id="docUploadId" widgetVar="docUploadWidgetVar" fileUploadListener="#{uploadDocumentBL.handleDocumentUpload}" mode="advanced"
dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true" fileLimit="#{uploadDocumentBL.fileCountUploadLimit}" sequential="true"
sizeLimit="#{uploadDocumentBL.fileSizeUploadLimitForOneFile}" cancelLabel="#{msgs['label.button.fileUpload.resetButton']}"
uploadLabel="#{msgs['label.button.fileUpload.uploadButton']}" label="#{msgs['label.button.fileUpload.chooseButton']}"
fileLimitMessage="#{msgs.getTextWithParams('msg.error.validation.upload.tooMuchFiles', uploadDocumentBL.fileCountUploadLimit)}"
invalidSizeMessage="#{uploadDocumentBL.getMaxFileSizeExceededValidationMessage()}" styleClass="uploadDocument" update="@this">
    <h:panelGroup id="dropZoneTextId" styleClass="dropZoneTextDiv" layout="block">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['label.documentUpload.fileDropZone']}" styleClass="dropZoneText" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: Does the problem disappear when you remove `cancelLabel` attribute?

Comment: Unexpectedly it does! The title is no more changed. But the cancel button is of course no more translated.

Comment: Sounds like a primefaces bug.